# Installing pip packages on TensorFlow base image (1.13.2-gpu-py3) not working

Tags: docker, tensorflow, dockerfile

I am simply trying to install JupyterLab and Keras as a pip package using a Dockerfile that is based on a TensorFlow image:

```
FROM tensorflow/tensorflow:1.13.2-gpu-py3
RUN apt-get update -y
RUN apt-get upgrade -y
RUN pip3 install --upgrade pip
RUN pip3 install jupyter jupyterlab keras
```

The install process runs through without any error messages but the packages are not available inside the container:

```
bash: jupyter: command not found
```

However, if I am accessing the container through the bash and execute the pip3 install commands within the running container, Jupyter works fine. It seems like the install instructions in the Dockerfile don't have any effect at all.

Am I missing something obvious here because I think I have done it this way a hundred times before without any problems.

Comment: can not re-produce working just fine

Comment: Can you share the commands you use to build and run the container? I have a feeling that you might start the container with an old image

Comment: Oh man, you are right. By forgetting to tag the image that was build by the Dockerfile I accidentally started the base image itself without the installed packages. Shame on me.